# How can I make changes to a flask app and used databases without reloading the page?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to implement some way of making changes to a web page and database without reloading the pages.

Hi all, I am creating a flask app that able to do the following: people are able to ask questions and then make comments that are attached to those questions. A person can make questions if they have an account, they can delete the questions if they're the person that posted it. Questions can be reported. All of this can also be done with comments.  I've gotten it all to work how I want.

The problem with how I did this is that the page has to re-load for the changes to take place. This is with the flask routes and html submit forms. So if a person makes a new comment, the whole page is reloaded and the person has to go back down to where they are if they want to keep looking at comments.

The following is how the information is sent to the flask routes so that pages are reloaded. It's an html file that shows all the info on the web page.

```
{% for item in htmlQuestion %}
      <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionPanel-Questions">
        <div class="accordion-item">

          <!-- This is where the three dots show up for the post options -->
          <div id = "test-cont">
            <div id="container">
              <div id="menu-wrap">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" />
                <div class="dots">
                  <div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                  
                    <ul class = "post-options">
                      {% if item.posterName == currentUser%}
                        
                          <form class = "input-group" action = "/deletePost/{{item._id}}/{{item.csClass}}" method = "post" id = "delete-button-form"> 
                            <input type = "submit" name = "submit-button" value = "Delete Post" id = "delete-post-box" />
                          </form>
                        
                      {% endif %}
                      <form class = "input-group" action = "/reportPost/{{item._id}}/{{item.csClass}}" method = "post"> 
                        <input type = "submit" name = "submit-button" value = "Report Post" id = "report-post-box" />
                      </form>
                    </ul>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- The rest of the info in the post header -->

          <h2 class="accordion-header" id = "accordionPanel-Questions">
            <button id = "post-button-info" class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-{{item._id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-{{item._id}}">
              <div class = "question-info">
                <p id = "question-info">Class: {{item.csClass}} Posted by: {{item.posterName}} </p><!-- .csCSClass, posterName, and ._id are all attributes in the db model -->
                <br>
                <div class = "question-header">
                  <p> <strong>Question: </strong> {{item.userQuestion}} </p>
                  <br>
                </div>
              </div>
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="panelsStayOpen-{{item._id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <p><strong>Comments: </strong></p>
                <br>

                <!-- TODO: changee the buttons so that they are '...' that give you the option to delete or report -->

                {% for comment in htmlResponses %}
                    {% if comment.post_id == item._id %}   
                      <div class = "comment-box">
                        <div class="dropdown-center">
                          <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id = "options-comment"> ... </button>
                          <ul class = "dropdown-menu"> 
                            <form class = "del-comm" action = "/reportComment/{{comment.id}}/{{item.csClass}}" method = "post"> 
                              <input type = "submit" name = "submit-button" value = "Report Comment" id = "delete-comment-box" />
                            </form>
                            {% if comment.posterUsername == currentUser %}
                              <!-- Kind of like the last if checking if currentUser is the same as the comment poster. If they are they can delete the post and if not
                                    they are not given the option to delete  -->
                              
                                <form class = "del-comm" action = "/deleteComment/{{comment.id}}/{{item.csClass}}" method = "post"> 
                                  <input type = "submit" name = "submit-button" value = "Delete Comment" id = "delete-comment-box" />
                                </form>
                              
                              {% endif %}
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                          <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
                          <p> Comment By: {{comment.posterUsername}}</p> 
                      </div>  
                      <br>
                    {% endif %}
                    
                {% endfor %}
                <form class = "input-group" action = "/createComment/{{item._id}}/{{item.csClass}}" method = "post"> 
                        <input type = "text" placeholder = "enter response..." id = "response-box" name = "userResponse" size = 40/> <!-- name is used in the python stuff and id is used in the css stuff -->
                        <input type = "submit" name = "submit-button" value = "Post Response" id = "create-comment-box" onkeydown = "return event.key != 'Enter';" />
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

The following are the flask routes that are used to make changes. One thing to note is that questions are grouped up by type. For testing  there is only CS-1, CS-2, ..., and general.

```
# allows the user that posted a post to delete and when a post is deleted, all comments associated with it are also deleted
# getting sent here is dependent on the html if 

@qANDa.route("/deletePost/<post_id>/<csClass>", methods = ["POST"])
def deletePost(post_id, csClass):
    post = Questions.query.filter_by(_id = post_id).delete()
    db.session.commit()
    question = Comment.query.filter_by(post_id = post_id).delete()
    db.session.commit()
    if csClass == "General":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewQ"))
    elif csClass == "CS-1":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS1"))
    elif csClass == "CS-2":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS2"))
    elif csClass == "CS-3":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS3"))
    elif csClass == "CS-4":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS4"))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewQ"))

# deletes a single comment in a post if the deleter is also the comment poster
# this is the same as the del post where it is called from html

@qANDa.route("/deleteComment/<post_id>/<csClass>", methods = ["POST"])
def deleteComment(post_id, csClass):
    post = Comment.query.filter_by(id = post_id).delete()
    db.session.commit()
    if csClass == "General":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewQ"))
    elif csClass == "CS-1":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS1"))
    elif csClass == "CS-2":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS2"))
    elif csClass == "CS-3":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS3"))
    elif csClass == "CS-4":
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewCS4"))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("qANDa.viewQ"))
```

The following is a route for viewing the questions and reloading the changes. There are more but they're all the same except for what the filter_by is looking for. (General, CS-1, etc. )

```
# just lets user view all post <! --- Changes later so that the post are organized by class rather than having them all in one place --- !>
@qANDa.route("/viewQuestions", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def viewQ():
    q = Questions.query.filter_by(csClass = "General")
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if q.count() == 0:
                return render_template("emptyClass.html")
        else:
            return render_template("viewQuestions.html", htmlQuestion = q, htmlResponses = Comment.query.all(), currentUser = current_user.username)
    else:
        if q.count() == 0:
            return render_template("emptyClass.html")
        return render_template("viewQuestions.html", htmlQuestion = q, htmlResponses = Comment.query.all(), currentUser = "notSignedIn")
```

The way I understand how this works is the following:

the submit-buttons, once clicked, send information to the flask routes.

depending on which button was clicked the comment/question is deleted from the SqlAlchemy database.

Once deleted, the url for what ever type of question was deleted is called. Showing the information and the changes that happened.

I want to be able to make changes and not reload the page but I don't know how to do that. I've looked into Ajax, and htmx but I don't really understand what's happening.

Does anyone know where I should be heading and what resources I can find to get this problem solved? If there are any question

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. HTMX (as you've mentioned) will be your easiest way to the goal here. There are quite a few examples on the their website to explain the front-end part of how it works. For example making a button that deletes an element etc.

Basically, you want to create a route for each type of operation (e.g. one route for delete and one for edit) where you also send information about which item you want to do stuff with. This could be a route like `/delete/<item_id>`. You want to make htmx call these urls (hx-get) on button clicks etc.

In each of these routes you create the logic for deleting or changing entries in your DB, and then return a response (e.g. "item has been deleted") to the frontend which HTMX will integrate into the html.